# How can I prevent an updated version of an AWS SSM document from triggering a State Manager Association?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have a State Manager state machine in AWS that is associated with an SSM document. The state machine runs an Automation document whenever the SSM document is updated. However, I don't want the state machine to run automatically when I update the SSM document with a new version.

I tried setting a fixed schedule for the state machine (cronjob), but it still runs whenever I update the SSM document. I think this might be because updating the SSM document increases the association version, which triggers the state machine.

Is there any way to prevent the state machine from running automatically when I update the SSM document with a new version? I want to be able to update the SSM document without triggering the state machine.